# Child process still did not exit

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, mysql5.5

My LAMP server recently froze and I rebooted it. I ran into some memory issues with MySQL after that that I was able to determine indicated my swapfile got disabled during the reboot. I re-enabled my swapfile, got MySQL to stop crashing and... Now Apache doesn't seem to be serving my site. My Apache error log is full of lines like `child process xxxx still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM` followed by `child process xxxx still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL`. There's hundreds of each of these, so it appears that Apache continually is spawning child processes that don't get anywhere. However, I'm not sure how to identify what these child processes are or how to troubleshoot further. Is there an easy way to identify that and begin troubleshooting what is causing them to freeze or fail without properly exiting?

I wasn't having any issues with Apache before my VM froze and I had to reboot and mess with swap and MySQL, so if there's something related to that I should be checking, any debugging tips would be appreciated.  I have restarted the Apache service a few times with no luck.

Comment: Troubleshooting: Enable mod_status with  ExtendedStatus to see what URL is being requested. Independently verify you can connect to mysql. Strace a child process before it is killed.

Comment: If swap is needed to get the processes running, then you have nowhere near enough RAM to handle the load on the system.  This sounds like swap [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) to me.

Comment: @yoonix this appears to be the case. I gave Digital Ocean more money and things seem smooth now. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @yoonix if you wanted to write that up as an answer, I'd gladly accept it